# Undefined reference for template function in c++

Tags: c++, typename, template-function

I have a `template` function and I always have error using `typename` in my variables.
I have two functions to call, they are

```
template <>
void caffe_axpy<float>(const int N, const float alpha, const float* X,
    float* Y) { cblas_saxpy(N, alpha, X, 1, Y, 1); }

template <>
void caffe_axpy<double>(const int N, const double alpha, const double* X,
    double* Y) { cblas_daxpy(N, alpha, X, 1, Y, 1); }
```

Since they can be double or float, then I made a template function as

```
template <typename Dtype>
void Blob<Dtype>::UpdateNew(Dtype decay, Dtype lr) {
  // We will perform update based on where the data is located.
  switch (data_->head()) {
  case SyncedMemory::HEAD_AT_CPU:
    // perform computation on CPU
    //this is using data and decay to update diff
    caffe_axpy<Dtype>(count_, (Dtype)decay,
        static_cast<const Dtype*>(data_->cpu_data()),
        static_cast<Dtype*>(diff_->mutable_cpu_data()));
    //this is using diff and lr to update data
    caffe_axpy<Dtype>(count_, (Dtype)lr,
        static_cast<const Dtype*>(diff_->cpu_data()),
        static_cast<Dtype*>(data_->mutable_cpu_data()));
    break;
  case SyncedMemory::HEAD_AT_GPU:
  case SyncedMemory::SYNCED:
#ifndef CPU_ONLY
    // perform computation on GPU
    //this is using data and decay to update diff
    caffe_gpu_axpy<Dtype>(count_, (Dtype)decay,
        static_cast<const Dtype*>(data_->gpu_data()),
        static_cast<Dtype*>(diff_->mutable_gpu_data()));
    //this is using diff and lr to update data
    caffe_gpu_axpy<Dtype>(count_, (float)lr,
        static_cast<const Dtype*>(diff_->gpu_data()),
        static_cast<Dtype*>(data_->mutable_gpu_data()));
#else
    NO_GPU;
#endif
    break;
  default:
    LOG(FATAL) << "Syncedmem not initialized.";
  }
}
```

If I change all the following lines from Dtype to float, then no error. If I use Dtype, then I have undefined reference errors.

```
caffe_axpy<float>(count_, (float)decay,
            static_cast<const Dtype*>(data_->cpu_data()),
            static_cast<float*>(diff_->mutable_cpu_data()));
        //this is using diff and lr to update data
caffe_axpy<float>(count_, (float)lr,
            static_cast<const float*>(diff_->cpu_data()),
            static_cast<float*>(data_->mutable_cpu_data()));
 caffe_gpu_axpy<float>(count_, (float)decay,
            static_cast<const float*>(data_->gpu_data()),
            static_cast<float*>(diff_->mutable_gpu_data()));
        //this is using diff and lr to update data
caffe_gpu_axpy<float>(count_, (float)lr,
            static_cast<const float*>(diff_->gpu_data()),
            static_cast<float*>(data_->mutable_gpu_data()));
```

What could be wrong?

EDIT:
The compile error is

```
debug_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `void caffe::caffe_axpy<unsigned int>(int, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int*)'
.debug_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `void caffe::caffe_gpu_axpy<unsigned int>(int, unsigned int, unsigned int const*, unsigned int*)'
.debug_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `void caffe::caffe_gpu_axpy<int>(int, int, int const*, int*)'
.debug_debug/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `void caffe::caffe_axpy<int>(int, int, int const*, int*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is `Dtype` in the error message? Is it something other than `float` or `double`? Please show the exact compiler output, don't make us guess. We can't see your screen.

Comment: Whenever you ask a question about an error message, it's extremely helpful to paste the entire error into the question.

Comment: Also, why is `caffe_axpy` even a template function? Why can it not simply be an overloaded function?

Comment: I have added errors in EDIT.

Comment: Somewhere in the code you haven't shown, you are instantiating `Blob<unsigned int>` and `Blob<int>`, and calling `UpdateNew` on those instances. Which in turn try to call `caffe_axpy<unsigned int>` and `caffe_axpy<int>`. But you haven't implemented the latter, so of course the linker complains.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks let me check, but I didn't notice I instantiated int.